# Excel - Filter table from one sheet to another using formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How can I filter my table from one sheet, into another sheet using formula? without a formula, I can just copy a reference of the cells like so:

```
=INDEX(MainSheet!A:A,ROW())
```

And then mark the range as a table, and then filter it by column, and then hide the column for readability. It doesn't look like a solution for me. I want to achieve that without hiding columns/rows in the filtered sheet.

For example, lets say I have 3 sheets:

- Main Sheet
- Sheet 2
- Sheet 3

In my "Main Sheet" sheet, I have:

```
| ID    | Name      | Filter To
|-------------------------------
| 1     | Record 1  | Sheet 2
| 2     | Record 2  | Sheet 3
| 3     | Record 3  | Sheet 2
| 4     | Record 4  | Sheet 2
| 5     | Record 5  | Sheet 3
```

What I want to do next, is to grab these cells, filter them by formula, and then place the filtered rows in the desired sheets ("Sheet 2" and "Sheet 3").

Comment: Did you create Filter to column for our help or is part of data?

Comment: @Rajesh I created a filter to column just for my help. I don't need to show it as a data.

Comment: But what are the criteria for the filters, if that "Filter to" column doesn't exist?

Comment: Why don't you use a [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576) in sheets 2 and 3? Each Pivot Table would be linked to the data in the Main sheet, and each can have different filters to show the rows you need.

Comment: Just to be clear, column **C** in the "Main Sheet" defines the destination sheet for that row ??

Comment: Tom - if there's an unexpected value in the column, then the record won't be displayed in the other sheets.

Comment: piko - Because I've been using it for a year, and there are some limita issues with it when u just want to take a part of the data without manipulating it.

Comment: Gary's - That's the purpose

Comment: Gary's - Yes. That's the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

With *Main Sheet* like:

[image]

In *Sheet 2*, cell **A1** enter:

```
=MATCH("Sheet 2",'Main Sheet'!C:C,0)
```

and in **A2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("Sheet 2",INDEX('Main Sheet'!C:C,A1+1):INDEX('Main Sheet'!C:C,9999),0)+A1,"")
```

Copy **A2** downwards.  In *Sheet 2* cell **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX('Main Sheet'!A:A,$A1)
```

and copy this both downwards and across.

[image]

Note column **A** identifies the row that the data is filtered from, columns **B** and **C** are the *Id* and *Name* from that row.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check and post back it out once I come back home.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Write Following Formula in Sheet2:**

*In Cell E242 Write this Array Formula, finish with Ctrl+Shift+Enter then fill it down:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(MainSheet!$A$242:$A$246,MATCH(0,IF($F$240=MainSheet!$C$242:$C$246,COUNTIF($E$241:$E241,MainSheet!$A$242:$A$246),""),0)),"")}
```

*In Cell F242 Write this Array Formula, finish with Ctrl+Shift+Enter then fill it down:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(MainSheet$B$242:$B$246, MATCH(0, IF($F$240=MainSheet!$C$242:$C$246, COUNTIF($F$241:$F241, MainSheet!$B$242:$B$246), ""), 0)),"")}
```

**Write Following Formula in Sheet3:**

*In Cell G242 Write this Array Formula, finish with Ctrl+Shift+Enter then fill it down:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(MainSheet!$A$242:$A$246,MATCH(0,IF($H$240=MainSheet!$C$242:$C$246,COUNTIF($G$241:$G241,MainSheet!$A$242:$A$246),""),0)),"")}
```

*In Cell H242 Write this Array Formula, finish with Ctrl+Shift+Enter then fill it down:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(MainSheet!$B$242:$B$246, MATCH(0, IF($H$240=MainSheet!$C$242:$C$246, COUNTIF($H$241:$H241, MainSheet!$B$242:$B$246), ""), 0)),"")}
```

**N.B.** *Adjust the Cell address in formula according to your need.*