# Alternative for a filter formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-excel-2019

I used a filter formula to find all data from another sheet and column, that start with "US".

In the column, I have about 5000 rows that have different data with different markets. And the next column is the market followed by its serial number: some are US1234, some Brazil1324, Canada1234, EMEA5432, Australia1234, and so on. I want the data that have "US" as a market from the column L, and I need the result from column K (market & serial number) .

It is an amazing formula because it automatically finds all the rows that start with the condition you set. But it's crushing Excel and it takes about 3 to 5 minutes every time.

The formula is:

```
=FILTER(tab1!L:L,tab1!K:K="US")
```

Does anyone know any good alternative for it?

Comment: The alternative to filter is `SUMPRODUCT`, I do not believe you will gain any speed on recalculation. The alternative approach is to turn calculations off.

Comment: If you don't want the `FILTER` formula to recalculate (because the result is relatively static), but want your other formulas to calculate, then an alternative may be a pivot table. You'll have to add an additional column in your raw data, otherwise the pivot table would only gather unique market/serial numbers. If you do want unique values only then you may be able to update your formula using `UNIQUE()` inside of your filter...

Comment: Try using a **Table** and avoid whole column references. Filter should not take that long for only 5,000 rows. But you have your question tagged with Excel 2010 and Excel 2007. The filter function does not exist in those versions. What is the reason for those tags?

Answer (score 1):

Since the formula works, adjusting the search range should help to reduce the formula load. Try :

```
=FILTER(tab1!L1:L6000,tab1!K1:K6000="US")
```

Please share if it works/not.

Comment: Still very slow. there's no formula or function that can do the same as the filter formula?

Comment: [there is](https://superuser.com/questions/1329320/excel-filter-table-from-one-sheet-to-another-using-formula?rq=1).. but need to generate extra helper column.